# Separate each entry of brace-enclosed lists with new-line via clang-format

Tags: clang-format

I have brace-enclosed lists to initialize an array.  I'd like to have my array initializers new-line for each entry of the array, which looks like:

```
const char* const array_of_strings[] = {
    "Hey",
    "Hi",
    "Hello",
    "Soup",
    "Atom"
};
```

Though, clang-format formats this array to:

```
const char *const array_of_strings[] = {"Hey", "Hi", "Hello", "Soup", "Atom"};
```

usually new lining once the list gets past *ColumnLimit*.  Is my wanted formatting possible using clang-format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is mostly possible. You need two things:

- Set the `BinPackArguments` style option to `false`. I guess clang-format is treating the brace-enclosed initializer list as arguments. (The [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) doesn't really specify this, but it seems reasonable.)
- Use the comma-after-last-item feature. To do this, add a comma between "Atom" and the closing brace. This feature is not documented anywhere that I've seen, but it has been in clang-format for many versions and many years.

With both of the above, and otherwise default clang-format settings, your output would look like:

```
const char *const array_of_strings[] = {
    "Hey",
    "Hi",
    "Hello",
    "Soup",
    "Atom",
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this works wonderfully!  It is interesting that the comma-after-last-item feature is needed.  Without it, clang-format tries to put the first element and last element on the same line as the brackets.  It'd be interesting to see if that feature is actually documented or not.